# Can a Pokémon be both Shiny and Lucky?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the newest update, traded Pokémon have a chance to be Lucky. Can Shiny Pokémon also become Lucky?

So far all I have found is speculation, some saying that it is possible, and others saying it is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is my first post on here (hopefully I’ve done it right!)
I was lucky to end up with a 100% lucky shiny Eevee following a trade, so it is possible, but up to RNG.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes, it is possible.

Evidenced by another user in my town's Discord group, *screenshot used with permission*.

[image: Shiny and Lucky Eevee]